# Node is slowing down in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an arcade game, where a ball moves at a constant speed and is unaffected by gravity or friction. So I created the ball as an `SKShapeNode` and set its `linearDamping` and `friction` to `0`. I also set the game scene to have no gravity. But when playing, if the ball hits another shape node (a circle) at a low angle, it can slow down. The ball's `restitution` is `1`, and `allowsRotation` is `false`.

I am keeping the ball moving by applying one impulse at the beginning of the game, that is a random direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most ideal fix but you could set the fixed speed of the object every update to a specific value which is your constant speed.

The other alternative way to solve this would be to set the fixed speed of the object under the collision delegate functions.

Comment: Under the update function, I tried setting the ball's `speed` to `1.0` but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Is 1.0 the constant speed of your ball? If that's so then it's strange if it doesn't work because it should override the cause of the slowing of the speed. You can try setting the speed under the collision delegates method and see if it works?

Comment: What about AngularDamping, is it set to 0? http://www.raywenderlich.com/84341/create-breakout-game-sprite-kit-swift. This might help you since it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was resolved by setting `physicsBody?.isDynamic = false` on the node that the ball makes contact with.

For example if you have a ball and a brick:

```
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.width / 2) // (diameter / 2) = radius
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategoryBitMask
// Detect contact with the bottom of the screen or a brick
//
ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bottomCategoryBitMask | brickCategoryBitMask
ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: -10))

brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brick.frame.size)
brick.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
brick.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
brick.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false // Prevents the ball slowing down when it gets hit
brick.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
brick.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
```